# Context: \defineparagraphs aligned to grid?

Tags: context, grids

I am a beginner in ConTeXt, and I don't understand why `\defineparagraphs` turns off grid alignment here:

```
\showgrid
\setuplayout [grid=yes]

\defineparagraphs[AntiphonNo][n=2]
\setupparagraphs[AntiphonNo][1][width=30pt, color=red]

\starttext

This is aligned just fine.

\startAntiphonNo
Col. 1\AntiphonNo
This is not aligned, and I don't know why.
\stopAntiphonNo

This is aligned just fine.

\stoptext
```

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Should I just fix it with `\godown`?

```
\showgrid
\setuplayout [grid=yes]



\defineparagraphs[AntiphonNo][n=2]
\setupparagraphs[AntiphonNo][1][width=30pt, color=red, tolerance=strict]

\starttext

This is aligned just fine.

\godown[4.1pt]
\startAntiphonNo
Col. 1\AntiphonNo
This is not aligned, and I don't know why.
\stopAntiphonNo
\godown[-4.2pt]

This is aligned just fine.

\stoptext
```

[image: Fixed layout]

Comment: Added comments and screenshot of the problem

Comment: @Sebastiano This is a ConTeXt example and is compilable.

Comment: No answers? Is this a hard question?

Comment: @NeilMussett It is not a hard question, there are just not many ConTeXt users around here.  Also, you shouldn't be so impatient and demanding.  People here are volunteers and answer questions in their spare time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you should always keep in mind is that `paragraphs` counts as a table environment and not as columns which means `grid` snapping of the content isn’t a priority.

In the past the content of the environment was on the grid because it used just a few nested horizontal and vertical boxes but since a while the result of the environment is put in a `\framed` block.

By default `\framed` stays always one the baseline of the text which means all characters are too high.

```
\setuppapersize [A6,landscape]

\defineparagraphs [test] [n=2]

\setuplayout [grid=yes]

\setupparagraphs [test] [frame=on]

\showgrid [lines]

\starttext

text

\startparagraphs [test]
  \startparagraphscell
    Weisman
  \stopparagraphscell
  \startparagraphscell
    \samplefile{weisman}
  \stopparagraphscell
\stopparagraphs

\stoptext
```

[image]

You can change the vertical position of `\framed` with the `location` key where two options are available in your case. You can either use `location=bottom` or `location=depth` to shift the box down.

```
\setuppapersize [A6,landscape]

\defineparagraphs [test] [n=2]

\setuplayout [grid=yes]

\setupparagraphs [test] [frame=on]
\setupparagraphs [test] [location=depth]

\showgrid [lines]

\starttext

text

\startparagraphs [test]
  \startparagraphscell
    Weisman
  \stopparagraphscell
  \startparagraphscell
    \samplefile{weisman}
  \stopparagraphscell
\stopparagraphs

\stoptext
```

[image]

While `location=low` seems like another possible settings to get the content on the baseline it works only when you have only a single line of text. When you have more text only the last line appears on the correct position and everything else is moved upwards.

```
\setuppapersize [A6,landscape]

\defineparagraphs [test] [n=2]

\setuplayout [grid=yes]

\setupparagraphs [test] [frame=on]
\setupparagraphs [test] [location=low]

\showgrid [lines]

\starttext

text

\startparagraphs [test]
  \startparagraphscell
    Weisman
  \stopparagraphscell
  \startparagraphscell
    \samplefile{weisman}
  \stopparagraphscell
\stopparagraphs

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! `location=depth` is exactly what fixed my issue. Thank you for taking the time to explain the whole thing to me. This should be in the wiki! :)